# Уменьшить размер apk на Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, оптимизация, apk

---

Помню писал почти год назад приложение, вышел размер около 3мб, а сейчас, написал его у нуля, использовав другие методы, гораздо меньше кода, но размер стал 14мб. И не пойму из-за чего. Вотскин градла. Может есть какие-то варианты уменьшения размера апк? Серфил все сайты, ничего не помогло.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: из за подключенных библиотек, в прошлый раз вы такие же библиотеки подключали?

Comment: Новые только progress-button и eventbus, но 10мб они никак не могут весить.

Comment: proguard у вас отключен. А раньше, скорее всего, был включен

Comment: @rjhdby  `useProguard true` это? Включил и всё равно ничего не изменилось.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html